# How can I execute a least cost routing query in postgresql, without temporary tables?

Tags: postgresql

How can I execute a telecoms least cost routing query in PostgreSQL?
The purpose is generate a result set with ordered by the lowest price for the carriers. The table structure is below

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/480cc/1)

```
CREATE TABLE tariffs (
    trf_tariff_id integer,
    trf_carrier_id integer,
    trf_prefix character varying,
    trf_destination character varying,
    trf_price numeric(15,6),
    trf_connect_charge numeric(15,6),
    trf_billing_interval integer,
    trf_minimum_interval integer
);
```

For instance to check the cost for a call if passed through a particular carrier carrier_id the query is:

```
SELECT trf_price, trf_prefix as lmp FROM tariffs WHERE SUBSTRING(dialled_number,1, LENGTH(trf_prefix)) = trf_prefix and trf_carrier_id = carrier_id  ORDER BY trf_prefix DESC limit 1
```

For the cost of the call for each carrier ie the least cost query the query is:

```
-- select * from tariffs
select distinct banana2.longest_prefix, banana2.trf_carrier_id_2, apple2.trf_carrier_id, apple2.lenprefix, apple2.trf_price, apple2.trf_destination from 
(select banana.longest_prefix, banana.trf_carrier_id_2 from (select  max(length(trf_prefix)) as longest_prefix, trf_carrier_id as trf_carrier_id_2 from  (select *, length(trf_prefix) as lenprefix from tariffs where substring('35567234567', 1, length(trf_prefix) )= trf_prefix) as apple group by apple.trf_carrier_id) as banana) as banana2,

(select *, length(trf_prefix) as lenprefix from tariffs where substring('35567234567', 1, length(trf_prefix) )= trf_prefix) as apple2 -- group by apple2.trf_carrier_id where banana2.trf_carrier_id_2=apple2.trf_carrier_id and banana2.longest_prefix=apple2.lenprefix order by trf_price
```

The query works on the basis that for each carrier the longest matching prefix for a dialled number is unique and it will be the longest. So a join involving the longest prefix and carrier on the selection gives the set for all the carriers.

I one problem with my query:

I don't want to do the apple(X) query twice

```
(select *, length(trf_prefix) as lenprefix from tariffs where substring('35567234567', 1, length(trf_prefix) )= trf_prefix) as apple
```

There must be a more elegant way, probably declaring it once and using it twice.

What I want to do is run the query on the single carrier for each carrier:

```
SELECT trf_price, trf_prefix as lmp FROM tariffs WHERE SUBSTRING(dialled_number,1, LENGTH(trf_prefix)) = trf_prefix and trf_carrier_id = carrier_id  ORDER BY trf_prefix DESC limit 1
```

and combine them into one set which will be sorted by price.

In fact I want to generalize the method for any such query where the output for the various values for a particular column or set of columns are combined into one set for further querying. I am told that CTEs are the way to accomplish that kind of query but I find the docs rather confusing. It is much easier with your own use cases.

PS. I am aware that the prefix length can be precomputed and stored.

Comment: What did you try to do here: `SUBSTRING(prefix,1, LENGTH(prefix))`? And it seems that if you just drop the part about the `carrier_id` in the `WHERE` you're gonna have your answer.

Comment: @JakubKania There was an error in the query It should be `SELECT cost, prefix as lmp FROM carrier_prices WHERE SUBSTRING(dialled_number,1, LENGTH(prefix)) = prefix and carrier_id = :carrier_id ORDER BY prefix DESC limit 1`. `dialled_number` is the value in the SUBSTRING function

Comment: Sample data please - sqlfiddle.com if possible.

Comment: common table expressions? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html

Comment: It's probably not the answer to your question but if you want to match phone numbers you might want to use the Prefix Extension (https://github.com/dimitri/prefix/) then you can write simpler queries like "WHERE nr @> '35567234567'" to get all entries with "3", "355", "35567".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common Table Expressions:

```
with apple as (
 select *, length(trf_prefix) as lenprefix
   from tariffs
  where substring('35567234567', 1, length(trf_prefix)) = trf_prefix
)
select distinct banana2.longest_prefix, banana2.trf_carrier_id_2,
       apple.trf_carrier_id, apple.lenprefix, apple.trf_price,
       apple.trf_destination
from (select banana.longest_prefix, banana.trf_carrier_id_2
        from (select max(length(trf_prefix)) as longest_prefix,
                     trf_carrier_id as trf_carrier_id_2
                from apple
              group by apple.trf_carrier_id) as banana) as banana2,
     apple
where banana2.trf_carrier_id_2 = apple.trf_carrier_id
  and banana2.longest_prefix = apple.lenprefix
order by trf_price
```

You can just pull out the repeated table definition. Even if I'm just using one of those sub-select-in-a-from things a single time, I still use CTEs. I find the style you're using basically unreadable.

Comment: I am having a hard time formatting the queries for the SO edit box. Some of the queries don't wrap around as I expect. 
The reason I asked the question was to be able to use this query for a single carrier `SELECT trf_price, trf_prefix as lmp FROM tariffs WHERE SUBSTRING(dialled_number,1, LENGTH(trf_prefix)) = trf_prefix and trf_carrier_id = carrier_id  ORDER BY trf_prefix DESC limit 1`, combine them for all the carriers and run the price sort on it, as it is more readable. Any thoughts there?